# Simulate Double Click Event in IE EXCEL , VBA interaction

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Cant use fireevent because it halted all macro code
so i need to simulate the double click event
or if anyone kind enough to look into the problem and suggest a solution
..

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: hi . it's intranet and confidential web , so i cant share the URL / Code

Comment: i believe we can discuss the issue without the URL / HTML (jave code). From what i had tested so far, i believed after fireevent on double click , the code was stopped and waiting for event to complete before continue the excel vba code. which fail all the code to handle the prompter . the code application.sendkey works fine if i manually trigger the prompt (manual double click instead of fireevent) . so either we cna figure out what is the event currently running and stop it and return to the vba code or trying simulate double click and not using fireevents

Comment: Perhaps add a DoEvents

Comment: yeah. that cross my mind before and tried. may i did'nt code it correctly

Comment: edited again my original posted to include the part i try doevents.  it does'nt work  i am not sure if i had done it correctly. thank you for looking up for the problem =)

Comment: testing the doevents. seems only execute next line of code after first line code done . maybe i did'nt code it correctly. `code` Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
MsgBox "5 sc"
DoEvents
MsgBox "ok" `code`

Comment: try replacing that entire loop with something like this: https://pastebin.com/t0k0uZMw

Comment: thanks for suggestion. will try it . do i need bind or declare anything to use query selector  ? it was interesting feature but i am confused how to work with it

Comment: no you don't need to declare anything. It is a method of HTMLDocument (e.g. ie.document) .  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: okie . will give it a try . was wondering any simple and easy to understand example of css usage ? i knew it was useful, but i cant get a workable method as off now . after this done , i also will try improve my skills by doing other type of automation. and it consist a lot of iframe , form , table , nested table and etc. it's ofter we can see the item thru dom explorer, yet unable to access it

Comment: sample code as below . it's the web i used to train the skills and the given code is consider simple type . cause it only had table . [link](https://pastebin.com/KT79UeKh)[link]

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) explains and you can experiment [here](https://flukeout.github.io/)

Comment: Had try the suggested code using query selector. Still same, stucked after prompt triggered =(. But idea of query selector was great. Especially the training side

Comment: Is there any possibilities that we simulate double click event?

Comment: which kind of prompt are you meeting? could you capture a screenshot to display it?

Comment: Hi. Just a simple message from website prompt. Let u click OK or cancel. No issue to code the handle, problem is all code stopped after double click,.. So all handler to dismiss code not working. No issue if I manual trigger the prompt then send the code to dismiss it.. I think fireevent double click had messed up the thing.

Comment: @QHarr . trying to use queryselector. got this error. any thoughts to improve it ?Z = objIE.document.querySelectorAll("tr")(2)
MsgBox Z

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Something like automation error. Trying to grab all item inside the element and click it based on index. Just trying out

Comment: Qharr. please marked it as answered . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample to reproduce the problem, it seems that when the prompt displaying, the VBA script will hang and waiting for us to handle the prompt. Unless we handle the prompt, we can do nothing.

As a workaround, I suggest you could try to use [Selenium IE webdriver](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/), By using this method, after click the button, we could switch to the popup window, then click the OK/Cancel button.

More detail information, you could check the following articles:

[Python Selenium handle alerts prompts confirmation popups](http://allselenium.info/python-selenium-handle-alerts-prompts-confirmation-popups/)

Comment: Thanks for su gg. Cannot add in plug in in working station? U had any Web that able to repdocue the issue?, double click then prompt the stopped. If single click no issue, code able handle the prompt

Comment: I just create a web site, in the Ondblclick event using Javascript alert () or prompts () method to display the prompt, when the prompt displays, the VBA script will hang and waiting for us to handle the prompt, after close the prompt, it will continue to execute the VBA Script.

Comment: ooO. can help check what if  it was single left mouse click?

Comment: i had application sendkey work fine for single left mouse click .. but it halted when it come in double click

Comment: No matter the single click event and the double click event, when the prompt display, the script will hang on my side, until I close the prompt.